# Broadcast data from FCM while app is in foreground not getting in BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, firebase, broadcastreceiver, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using firebase push notification in my app,In case of app in foreground, i am broadcasting an intent to another activity on receiving the message. But i am not getting the intent in the BroadcastReceiver written in the directed activity.

sending intent  is like

```
 @Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

    if (isAppIsInBackground(this)){ 
        int dbcount = Integer.parseInt(dbHelper.getPushCount());
        int i = count;
        int current = dbcount +4;
        dbHelper.updatePushCount(Integer.toString(current));
    } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NavigationHome.class);
        intent.setAction("new.pushMessage");
        intent.putExtra("count", count.toString());
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}
```

and receiver in the activity in which i want to get the intent is

```
public class NavigationHome extends BaseActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

int count=0;
Context context;
private BroadcastReceiver LandingBr = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.e("received",""+1);
        NavigationHome.this.update();
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation_home);

    dbhelper = new DBHelper(this);
```

...................

update() function is not getting called, How can i get the intent in the Activity?

Comment: Have you registered your receiver in manifest file?

Comment: you have to register BroadcastReceiver in Activity.

Comment: why its required to do so? I have defined it within the Activity itself. Could you please make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

Create MyReceiver class extending BroadcastReceiver in activity.

```
class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // do your stuff here
    }
}
```

and than register your BroadcastReceiver in onCreate() of Particular activity . use following code for that.

```
MyReceiver myReceiver =new MyReceiver();
IntentFilter intentFilter= new IntentFilter(Constants.ACTION);
registerReceiver(myReceiver,intentFilter);
```

Comment: it too not working. could you tell whats wrong with my code.